# Create work items in Team Service in mass

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-workitem

I am doing a test.And the test case need the Team service account had more than 200 work items.I can not create them manually.So I am wandering if there any command can help me create work items in mass.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Excel to add work items, refer to this link for details: [Bulk add or modify work items with Excel](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel).